# .net generic typing object to a different type than it holds

Tags: c#, .net, generics

An object value from a third party application provides a value that is correct but incorrectly typed. I'm trying to Type this object value in an generic method i'm creating into the type of my choosing. I've mocked up an example to demonstrate the problem.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    decimal d = 1; // this can't be changed
    var v = Method<int>(d); // what I'm trying to do
}

//the code in this method can be changed
static T Method<T>(object input)
{
    T output = default(T);

    //causes InvalidCastException
    output = (T)input;

    return output;
}
```

As you can see the value '1' is an valid integer, however as the third party application types it as a decimal, when trying to convert it to an integer it falls over. How can the generic method be changed so that it can won't fall over for this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `output = (T)input;` with:

```
output = (T)Convert.ChangeType(input, typeof(T));
```

Comment: This will only work for a limited set of `T` and input types (Namely items implementing `IConvertable` going to an item `IConvertable` converts to.), even though it *appears* to handle the general case.  It's misleading in that regard.

Comment: This scenario is simple and meets the need. A bit of error handling was added to complete this answer, however this is what was used in the end. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
static T Method<T>(object input)
{
    T output = default(T);

    var t = input.GetType();
    TypeConverter tc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(t);
    output = (T)tc.ConvertTo(input, typeof(T));

    return output;
}
```

Obviously you'd want to add some error checking to make sure the types are compatible -- look at the methods on TypeConverter.

You'll need to add a `using System.ComponentModel;`

Comment: This might be overkill for the above solution, however I like this answer, and in a more extensive scenario, this is what I would choose.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

"Casting" and "Converting" are two very different things.  Unfortunately, in certain instances the syntax in C# is the same, so that can confuse the topic.

`input` can only be *cast* to a `decimal`, since that's what it really is.  You can convert a `decimal` to an `int`, but you can't convert and `object` that happens to contain a `decimal` to an `int`.

So if you do:

```
static int ToInt(object input)
{
    return (int)(decimal)input;
}
```

Then it will work.

If you want to handle the general case where there is a *conversion* operator from whatever `input` is to `T` then you're pretty much out of luck.  Those conversions are compile time mechanisms, not runtime mechanisms.

Comment: What if the input was double? let me say, it will get runtime error

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad Sure.  If you're input is a double then you should cast it to a `double` instead of to a `decimal`.  If someone wrote a method that sometimes returns one, and sometimes the other, then go find that person and beat them with a hose because they did it wrong and there is no general case solution for handling a method that returned some object that has an explicit conversion operator to `int`.  You could switch on the type to handle the common ones (double, decimal, long, byte, char, etc.) but it's *impossible* to handle the general case, as my answer states.